# non-numeric argument to 'pairs' in R when I tried include location

Tags: r

[image: This is how my data looks like]

```
pairs(~bedroom+bathroom+parking+taxes+lotsize+location,
      data=x,gap=0.4,cex.labels=0.85)
numericx=cbind(bedroom,bathroom,parking,taxes,lotsize)
round(cor(numericxy,use = "complete.obs"), 4)
pairs(sale~bedroom+bathroom+parking+taxes+lotsize,data=x,cex.labels=0.85)
numericxy=cbind(sale,numericx)
round(cor(numericxy), 4)
```

I tried using above code to generate pairwise correlation map yet my location is labeled as M and T.Is there any ways I can fit location into this correlation map?
Thanks

Comment: As you can see, your location column is of type character (which means text), so you can't do correlations with this column. You need to convert it to a numeric column first.

Answer (score 0):

Try sth. like the following on your location column:

```
x$location_new <- as.numeric(type.convert(x$location))
```

and then run your code, but replace the old location column with this new one.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is just going to lead to a bunch of `NA` values?? `as.numeric(type.convert(c("T","M")))`

Comment: Does it? I get values 2 and 1 with your code.

Comment: type.convert will first convert the character column to a factor one, from which you can easily convert to numeric. Whether it makes sense to calculate Pearson's correlation on a binary variable, is another story...

Comment: this is a difference between R versions (I'm using >4.0.0).

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference for me. (I'm using R 4.0.3 btw). An alternative would be to use `as.numeric(as.factor(c("T","M")))`